# "Connect via network" wireless debugging not working Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, xcode9

I am trying to run my iOS app via wifi network. But its not working as I expected.

**Connected Network sign is not displaying**.

[image]

I am using:

**macOS Sierra - 10.12.6 (in Mac mini)**

**Xcode - 9.0 (9A235)**

**iOS - 11.0**

NOTE: Mac mini and iPhone both are connected to **same wifi network**.

**Already tried**:

1. Change another network
2. Restart iPhone and Mac mini twice.
3. Unpair Device and again pair device.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try removing passcode for the iPhone and adding it back again, and connect via network to see if it works.

Comment: Same problem here and I can't find a solution. I've installed the iOS 11 GM and Xcode 9 GM but can't make it work

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I was having the same issue and performed the following steps to get things working:

1. Open "Devices and Simulators"
2. Connect your device and check the "Connect via network" checkbox
3. Disconnect your device
4. Right click listing for your device in the left hand column (Under Disconnected)
5. Select "Connect via IP Address.." and enter your device's IP address

[image]

Comment: For me its keep rotating after entering ip address.

Comment: Does this still work if I go somewhere else, therefore using a different IP address?

Comment: Ok, tested it out - it still does work from any IP address.

Comment: this works for me, but I need to unpair device first

Comment: "its keep rotating after entering ip address" - No need to wait until it done. Just close the 'enter ip' dialog and try to run a debug build. It works for me.

Answer (score 10):

After numerous Wi-fi resets and device restarts (for iOS 12, Xcode 10) I found the solution for me was:

1. Disconnect iOS device from Mac
2. Go to Settings -> Develop on the iOS device
3. Tap "Clear Trusted Computers"
4. Reconnect iOS device to Mac via cable
5. On iOS device tap "Trust This Computer" and enter passcode
6. Go to Device Manager in Xcode and enable "Connect Via Network"

The network symbol appeared and I was good to go.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me (iPadOS 13.3.1, macOS Catalina, Xcode 11.3.1)

Comment: But what with Apple TV? I have the same problem being also on Xcode 11.3.1 with tvOS 13.4. "Device Support" folder added

Comment: @Sebastian OP is asking about iOS, so this solution is specific there. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into issues because I had a vpn running on my phone & computer. When I turned those off everything worked like it should.

Comment: same situation here, disconnecting the VPN worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites: iOS => 11.0; Xcode 9; Same network for both iOS device and Mac

This worked for me:
 1. Plug in iPhone, select "Connect via network"
 2. Select you iPhone as the target for debug build. 
 3. Unplug, build app in that iPhone (it will fail).
 4. Plug back in, check for network symbol (it appeared here for me). 
 5. Unplug and build wirelessly successfully.

Sorry this is a hand-waivey answer :/

Comment: One more thing you could try - log in to your router and clear the MAC addresses OR power off the router and turn back on (I'm sure you have already done this but I thought I'd recommend anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out.
Plug cable in, run app (must setting connect to network), and stop.
Plug cable out, go to Debug > Attach to process (select your app)
now its working