# Wireless debugging icon not showing in my Xcode 9

Tags: debugging, ios11, xcode9

I just download Xcode 9 and was going through wireless debugging tutorials . I went through this link [Wireless debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382841/how-do-you-perform-wireless-debugging-in-xcode-9-with-ios-11) but could not make out why my wireless debugging icon is not showing. My device is iPhone 6s updated to iOS 11. [image: network icon is checked] and the debugging icon is missing . Snaphot [image: Debugging over network icon is missing here here] . The icon is missing.
      What I got from others tutorial, is the icon they are getting, which I am not getting. Like this in apple documents. [image].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Network icon is not showing because your device is not paired up to the MAC you are using. If it's not working by connecting to the same WiFi network. you can connect to same network via Bluetooth.

1. Turn on Bluetooth of your device.
2. Turn on Bluetooth of your MAC.
3. Pair up the MAC to the device Bluetooth.

You can see the network icon next to the device name in Xcode -> window -> Devices & Simulator -> select the device.

This worked for me. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

The following steps worked for me:

1. Connect the iPhone to your mac book
2. Wait until the device setup is completed
3. Make sure the mac book and your iPhone are connected to the same Wifi network
4. In Xcode, Open Window -> Devices and Simulators and see the device appearing under the list of Connected devices.
5. Select your device and check the "Connect via network" box

[image]

5. Disconnect the device from your mac.
6. The device will appear under the list of disconnected devices in the same window.
7. Right click on your device and select "Connect via IP Address"

[image]

8. Enter the IP address of your phone and click connect.

To get the IP address of your iPhone:

1. On your iPhone, go to Settings -> Wi-FI and tap on the connected wifi network.
2. You will be able to see the your iPhone's current IP address for the selected Wi-Fi network.

[image]

This is working for me without any issues. Hope it helps you too

Comment: Thank you! Connecting by IP address worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

After pairing the iPad with my mac over bluetooth I didn't got that network icon on the iPad on the device list. Then I start to check for install provisioning profile. And immediately Xcode automatically sync the profile and seems all good for me.

The iPad was new, and it didn't have the provisioning profile install on it.

To check the provisioning profile. Press `command` + `shift` + `2` to open the `Devices and Simulators`. Select the `Device` category. Under `Device` category there is the list of connected device. Just press the right button of the mouse or two finger tap on the device.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to un-pair the device, and then I tapped "Trust computer" on the iPhone and then the network globe reappeared.
[image]