# Solution for wireless debug in Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, xcode

I upgraded Xcode to 9.3 and version of my iOS is 11.3 (15E216).

I can debug my app by cable but I configured Xcode for wireless debug but the network icon is not showing next to my device and wireless debug is not working.

(I connect my ac and iphPone to one modem, I check the connect via network and I restart Xcode and restart modem but it is not working).

What is solution?

Comment: I think your best course of action is to file a bug report with Apple. They may have advertised this feature a little prematurely (not the first time they've done that kind of thing).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 9 Wireless debugging not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358154/xcode-9-wireless-debugging-not-working)